# How to create side output layer with Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I try to make deep-learning model from this [Article](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/19/18/3921)

[image]

```
# My code now
img_rows, img_cols = 3280, 2464
input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

As you can see from picture, it has branch layers(In red rectangle) then concatenate later.

How to do that properly in Keras, or I need to use tensorflow?

Comment: You should use The Functional API: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't implement the network with a sequential API, use the functional API of keras, with that it's a piece of cake.

This is an example of concatenation of parallel layers with the functional API of keras.

```
  branchA = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')(input_layer)

  branchB = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')(input_layer)

  branchC = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')(input_layer)
  branchC = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')(branchC )

  branchD = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')(input_layer)
  branchD = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')(branchD )
  branchD = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')(branchD )

  finconc = concatenate([branchA, branchB, branchC, branchD], axis=-1)
```

reference here:
https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

Comment: can one factor out `the_conv = Conv3D(...)` and then use it like `some_branch = the_conv(input_layer); other_branch = the_conv(some_branch)` etc?

Comment: if i want to reuse a piece of code i usually define a function with the convolution inside, and then call the function every time, i did a quick test and what you propose does not work, even if the networks gets created a cycle is formed, the shape of the network is not the one you would expect

Comment: one way to refactor this code would be to create a function where you specify the number of consecutive convolution with an argument and the call it 4 times for each branch ( with argument 1 for branches A and B, with argument 2 for C and 3 for D)